# Drupal 7 Views 3 Fatal error: Cannot access protected property SelectQuery::$where

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am getting this error when attempting to modify a value in a Drupal 7 Views 3 filter:

```
Fatal error: Cannot access protected property SelectQuery::$where in /Users/joe/Sites/sdgea/docroot/sites/all/modules/custom/sdge_video/sdge_video.module on line 275
```

Here is the code that is causing this:

```
function modulename_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
  if (is_numeric($term_no)) {
        // set the filter
    $view->filter['tid']->value[$term_no] = $term_no;
        // set the query
        $view->query->where[0]['conditions'][2]['value'] = $term_no;
        // set the build info
        $view->build_info['query']->where->conditions[0]['field']->conditions[0]['field']->conditions[2]['value'] = $term_no;
        //$view->build_info['query']->where->conditions[0]['field']->conditions[0]['field']->conditions[2]['value'] = $term_no; // <-- This line specifically is causing fatality.
  }
}
```

Probably part of some superhuman object yada yada in D7. Anyone have any ideas on how I can modify the value of a filter in a views 3 view (D7).

And also, request an answer of why access to a "protected property" is happening. I am a coder. I don't want anything protected!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bit late but you can modify it using the **hook_views_query_alter**, which is exactly for that purpose, like this:

```
function modulename_views_query_alter(&$views,&$query){
    //...rest of the code
    $query->where[0]['conditions'][2]['value'] = $term_no;
}
```